# Mobile Device Detection in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following is a Mobile device detection code which encompasses three different conditions

```
if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
{
   //Do Something
}
else if (((System.Web.Configuration.HttpCapabilitiesBase)myBrowserCaps).IsMobileDevice)
{
  //Do Something
}
else if (IsMobileDevice(mobileDevices))
{
  //Do Something
}

public bool IsMobileDevice()
{
     private static string[] mobileDevices = new string[] {"iphone","ppc"
                                                   "windows ce","blackberry",
                                                   "opera mini","mobile","palm"
                                                   "portable","opera mobi" };

         string userAgent = Request.UserAgent.ToString().ToLower();
         return mobileDevices.Any(x => userAgent.Contains(x));
 }
```

I was forced to write three conditions as they were failing for some devices.

Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting Requests from Mobile Browsers in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653765/detecting-requests-from-mobile-browsers-in-asp-net)

Comment: Detect a device from an user agent string it's not easy as it seems because browsers uses to lie.
I am working to port a true parser bases on Antlr runtime for .NET, you can take a look there: https://github.com/OrbintSoft/yauaa.netstandard

Answer (score 78):

taking and change a bit the code from : http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

```
public static class Utils
{    
    // update : 5/April/2018
    static Regex MobileCheck = new Regex(@"(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    static Regex MobileVersionCheck = new Regex(@"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public static bool fBrowserIsMobile()
    {
        Debug.Assert(HttpContext.Current != null);

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] != null)
        {
            var u = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].ToString();

            if (u.Length < 4)
                return false;

            if (MobileCheck.IsMatch(u) || MobileVersionCheck.IsMatch(u.Substring(0, 4)))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and this is how you call it.

```
if (Utils.fBrowserIsMobile())
{
    // go to mobile pages
}
```

What I have change to the code from `http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/`

- Make static compile the Regex for faster check.
- Fix a bug in the case that u is less than 4 characters.
- Other checks.

### Using Cache

This code is fast, and the one trick is that we have made static and pre compile the regex. How ever i suggest after the first check to save the result on user session and use that session variable that is a lot faster.

Comment: @Aristos: I tried it twice, recompiled everything; deleted out all old stuff. Same problem (and in fact i did that already yesterday, since i was really astonished about the poor performance - otherwise i wouldn't have posted).

Comment: @johngrinder I believe you, but you may have some other issues... my sites, that use this routine and other are extreme fast... how ever because I cache the results, if I find time I will timing it and come back with results.

Comment: @Aristos Doesnt Detect Andriod Version 2.3.5HTC 3.0 Softwae Number 3.13.661.4 As mobile

Comment: @Apollo On first call of home page, or on each page of your site when first called - there you check if this is a mobile and you redirect them on the "same" mobile page if you can - The home page is the easy one, because you have only one check, and you know where to send them... I make only one check per user, then I store the results on session and not check again ! Also I have place that code on a dll library that I use on the site, on a global static class.

Comment: Was very helpful for me. Just can you please tell me why they should be static? Is static make problems here if I have more than 1000 request per second or not? Can you please tell me about static usage here? Thanks.

Comment: @user5032790 Yes - if you do it static, then the regedit is compile the request and keep that in memory - if not make it static, the regedit is compile it in every call and this is slow. All that you place it inside a class (static class) and you easy call it. I have update the code to full working class . You dont need to make it static, but its a lot faster.

Comment: @BradyMoritz Thank you for this note, I need to fist check it out first because this code is working years now correct. Now I check the source code, in the System.dll the source inside is the same - from system.web is complicate

Comment: For those looking for a ASP.NET Core version of the code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68641796

Comment: this is also works on core - and this is better because its keep the check on static and run fast

Comment: @Aristos "HttpContext.Current" definition does not exists in .net Core

Comment: @sTx @sTx when I write that, before 10 years, core did not even exist. - you only need to get the `"HTTP_USER_AGENT"` from the core - I search and found this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664770/how-to-get-user-browser-name-user-agent-in-asp-net-core

Comment: @Aristos My comment was more a reply to "this is also works on core - and this is better because its keep the check on static and run fast ". Anyway I've managed to make it work using https://stackoverflow.com/a/68641796/5393271  and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uflFOfVgec by sending `httpContext` to `isMobileDeviceBrowser(httpCOntext _httpContext)` and keeping regexp on static class. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: To set up session caching check out his link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14138911/14199515

Answer (score 6):

I'm using DeviceDetector.NET since I often also need to separate smartphones and tablets

Install it
`Install-Package DeviceDetector.NET`

Then use it like this

```
DeviceDetectorSettings.RegexesDirectory = "C:\\DeviceDetector.NET.3.11.4\\";
var dd = new DeviceDetector(Request.UserAgent);
dd.Parse();

var device = dd.GetDeviceName();

if(device == "tablet") {}
if(device == "smartphone") {}
if(device == "desktop") {}

/**
Possible returns
--
desktop
smartphone
tablet
feature phone
console
tv
car browser
smart display
camera
portable media player
phablet
**/
```

The regexes can be found in the packages directory

Answer (score 5):

This code works in my case.

```
public void IsMobileBrowser()
{
    String labelText = "";
    System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities myBrowserCaps = Request.Browser;
    if (((System.Web.Configuration.HttpCapabilitiesBase)myBrowserCaps).IsMobileDevice)
    {
        labelText = "Browser is a mobile device.";
    }
    else
    {
        labelText = "Browser is not a mobile device.";
    }
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "", "alert('"+ labelText + "');", true);
}
```

Reference: [HttpCapabilitiesBase.IsMobileDevice Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.ismobiledevice.aspx)

Comment: why `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` vs  `((System.Web.Configuration.HttpCapabilitiesBase)myBrowserCaps).IsMobileDevice` ?

Comment: Because of Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice was failed to detect some devices that's why I recommend this option @Kiquenet

Answer (score 4):

Scott Hanselman has a great [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreateAGreatMobileExperienceForYourWebsiteTodayPlease.aspx) on the subject. He refers to a 3rd party solution called 51Degrees.

Comment: I'm having a heck of a time with that lib. It keeps maxing my CPU

Answer (score 3):

The existing browser definitions are terrible. Ideally you want to use the [WURFL database](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) to augment those definitions.

Luckily this is pretty easy using the [51 Degrees.mobi library](http://51degrees.mobi/Products/Framework.aspx).

There is also a [Nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/51Degrees.mobi):

```
Install-Package 51Degrees.mobi
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest storing the list of user agents in the web.config to make it easier to configure. `IsMobileDevice` is not actively updated with new browsers therefore it does have it's limitations which is why you need the further check.

The [51Degrees.mobi](http://nuget.org/packages/51Degrees.mobi) package would be a more reliable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Check the UserAgent in codebehind for "Mobi" similar to javascript referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery).

```
                if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("Mobi") == true)
                {
                    DivToShowWhenMobileDevice.Style.Add("display", "");
                }
                else
                {
                    DivToShowWhenMobileDevice.Style.Add("display", "none");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, if you want to be sure the useragent is probably the best way. You can also look at this method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.ismobiledevice.aspx

It should have some issues with new browsers and such. But it's this one of as you currently do.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
private void CheckDevice()
        {
            bool FirstTime = false;
            String userAgent = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
            ChangeAgent:
            if (FirstTime)
                userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.ToLower();
            Regex OS = new Regex(@"(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od|ad)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
            Regex device = new Regex(@"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
            String device_info = "";
            if (OS.IsMatch(userAgent.ToLower()))
            {
                device_info = OS.Match(userAgent).Groups[0].Value;
            }
            if (device.IsMatch(userAgent.ToLower().Substring(0, 4)))
            {
                device_info += device.Match(userAgent).Groups[0].Value;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(device_info))
            {
                if (device_info.ToLower().Contains("mobile"))
                    if (device_info.ToLower().Contains("android"))
                    {
                        hypAppLink.NavigateUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.AppName";
                        hdnIsMobile.Value = "1";
                    }
                lblWhichDeviceUse.Text = device_info;
            }
            else
                if (!FirstTime)
                {
                    FirstTime = true;
                    goto ChangeAgent;
                }
        }
```