# 51degreee foundation - not redirection for new mobile

Tags: asp.net, mobile, 51degrees

In `asp.net` the `51degree` is not detecting new useragent.

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-us; EVO Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
```

How can I ensure that new mobiles are also detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 51degree have their database into a zip, and encoded file. There is no way you can add this User-Agent by your self , you need to contact them and ask them to add it.

Or use other method (with less features) like: [Mobile Device Detection in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086856/mobile-device-detection-in-asp-net/13086894#13086894)

Comment: Thanks.. I have sent a request to 51degrees. I will wait for them to respond else I will opt for the option above.

Comment: @user1124707 You need to wait for the next database version !

Answer (score 1):

51Degree has a payment model where new useragents are added weekly if you pay.

If you dont pay, its updated once every 3 months I believe.

For more information:
http://51degrees.mobi/Products/DeviceDetection.aspx