# How to determine in ASP.NET C# that a request is coming from a PC or a mobile device

Tags: asp.net

How to determine in ASP.NET C# that a request is coming from personal computer or a mobile device. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can analyze property Request.Browser.Platform

Going in deep, you can define your own browser detection rules in App_Browsers for your app.

Answer (score 1):

51Degrees.mobi components for mobile web development. It’s provided as a .NET open source class library that detects mobile devices and browsers, enhancing the information available to .NET programmers

refer more about

http://51degrees.codeplex.com/

answered posts

[Mobile Device Detection in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086856/mobile-device-detection-in-asp-net?rq=1)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34422/Detecting-a-mobile-browser-in-ASP-NET