# How to redirect to mobile page when its mobile or tablet?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, redirect

I am using aspx pages in my website. when user open my [Desktop Website](http://blueburn.tk/) in mobile I want to go be redirected to my [Mobile Website](http://m.blueburn.tk). I am using C#.

Comment: Your mobile link shows an empty page.

Comment: you can achieve a redirect e.g. by returning http header "Location" in response to the request.

Comment: the link on your Desktop Version of the website to the mobile website returns a 404 error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mobile Device Detection in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086856/mobile-device-detection-in-asp-net)

Comment: Sorry unfortunately my mobile page under construction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either check for `Request.Browser["IsMobileDevice"] == "true"` using the framework as explained here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhhycabe%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Or you can use 51Degrees.mobi which is shown here:

http://51degrees.mobi/

A good comparission can be found here:

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Mobile-Device-Detection-and-Redirection-Using-ASP-NET.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can get `UserAgent` in C# using `Request.UserAgent`.

**Try this:**

```
string strUA = Request.UserAgent.Trim().ToLower();
bool isMobile = false;
    if (strUA .Contains("ipod") || strUA .Contains("iphone"))
        isMobile = true;

    if (strUA .Contains("android"))
        isMobile = true;

    if (strUA .Contains("opera mobi"))
        isMobile = true;

    if (strUA .Contains("windows phone os") && strUA .Contains("iemobile"))
        isMobile = true;

    if (strUA .Contains("palm")
        isMobile = true;

    bool MobileDevice = Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice;
    if(isMobile == true && MobileDevice == true)
    {
      string Url = ""; // Put your mobile site url
      Response.Redirect(Url);
    }
```

**Note: `IsMobileDevice` is not actively updated with new browsers.**

Some of the popular mobile devices/browsers won’t be detected using this way because ASP.NET browser files are not supported in Opera Mobile or Android devices.

As a fix of this problem is : use [51Degrees.Mobi package. 51Degrees.Mobi package](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/)

[Read this article: Mobile Device Detection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213825/ASP-net-Mobile-device-detection)

Answer (score 0):

What about using a simple page, with no MasterPage, that uses Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice (or other method) to determine mobile or not and then redirect to the appropriate LogOn page for mobile or desktop?

I am also uses a querystring in the URL:

```
ForceMobile = Request.QueryString["ForceMobile"];
//
if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice || ForceMobile == "Yes")
{
    Response.Redirect("~/_Mobile/mLogOn.aspx", false);
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("~/LogOn.aspx", false);
}
```

The benefits of this are ease of debugging and no post-back events caused by redirects directly in LogOn pages.