# How to get user Browser name ( user-agent ) in Asp.net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Can you please let me know how to get the browser's name that the client is using in MVC 6, ASP.NET 5?

Comment: [Browser detection using the user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent)

Answer (score 268, accepted):

I think this was an easy one. Got the answer in `Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString()`

Comment: this returned all browsers  names to me

Comment: @kobosh `Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString()`

Comment: Beware this will result if a KeyNotFoundException if the request has no User-Agent! Be sure to use .ContainsKey first to check!

Comment: Scratch that. it just returns "" instead for some reason. Hooray for consistency...

Comment: Some may prefer `Request.Headers[HeaderNames.UserAgent]` as avoiding the string literal (may not have worked in Core 1.0, not sure)

Comment: @WillDean this constant is in the Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers namespace.

Comment: this returned all names of browser but need only client browser details

Comment: I get `UAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36`, using Chrome.

Comment: What is *`HeaderNames`* ?

Comment: it is returning "" for me, any ideas how to get it to work

Comment: Some firewalls may strip the useragent-string, apparently

Answer (score 55):

For me `Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString()` did't help cause returning all browsers names so found following solution.

Installed [ua-parse](https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-csharp).

In controller `using UAParser;`

```
var userAgent = HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
var uaParser = Parser.GetDefault();
ClientInfo c = uaParser.Parse(userAgent);
```

after using above code was able to get browser details from userAgent by using `c.UA.Family + " " + c.UA.Major +"." + c.UA.Minor`
You can also get OS details like `c.OS.Family;`

Where `c.UA.Major` is a browser major version and `c.UA.Minor` is a browser minor version.

Comment: That is not a list of all browser names, that is what the browser is setting as the User-Agent. The UAParser knows how to take all those names and determine what the actual browser and OS it.

Comment: `ua-parse` valid for ***NET 6*** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet, I'm using UAParser, information from this library was enough for me, works like a charm :D

Answer (score 22):

```
userAgent = Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
```

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-get-OS-and-browser-c007dbf7 (link not live)
go for 4.8

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.useragent?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: That link is the best answer.  The User-Agent string is a string that you have to decipher and parse to get version information.  The classes supplied there do all the hard-work.

Comment: This answer is for .NET Framework, not .NET Core

Comment: I have a web app and about 95% of users send back a user agent. However, the rest do not. These are not bots because the users are making paid bookings. Can anyone explain why user agent would be null?  Most users are on mobile devices. Are there some browsers not returning ua?

Answer (score 11):

I have developed a library to extend ASP.NET Core to support web client browser information detection at [Wangkanai.Detection](https://github.com/wangkanai/Detection) This should let you identity the browser name.

```
namespace Wangkanai.Detection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the APIs for query client access device.
    /// </summary>
    public class DetectionService : IDetectionService
    {
        public HttpContext Context { get; }
        public IUserAgent UserAgent { get; }

        public DetectionService(IServiceProvider services)
        {
            if (services == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));

            this.Context = services.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
            this.UserAgent = CreateUserAgent(this.Context);
        }

        private IUserAgent CreateUserAgent(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Context)); 

            return new UserAgent(Context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this work? I see you have a `DeviceResolver.cs` to find out whether it's a mobile, table or desktop, but I can't see similar code to extract details of the user agent header.

Comment: I have updated the repo and the readme is getting more mature. https://github.com/wangkanai/Detection

Comment: **Wangkanai.Detection** in Nuget ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .net 6 or later it looks like there is a property you can use.  So if you are in a controller you can access it like this:

```
var userAgent = HttpContext.Request.Headers.UserAgent;
```

Or if you are not in a controller you can inject an implmentation of  IHttpContextAccessor and access for example like this

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
          _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;   
    }

    public string? GetUserAgent()
    {
        return _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Request.Headers.UserAgent;
    }
}
```

Note in you will need to register IHttpContextAccessor by adding the following in your program.cs or startup.cs by adding this line of code

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Answer (score 1):

Install this [.nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OrbintSoft.Yauaa.NetStandard/)

create a class like this:

```
public static class YauaaSingleton
    {
        private static UserAgentAnalyzer.UserAgentAnalyzerBuilder Builder { get; }

        private static UserAgentAnalyzer analyzer = null;

        public static UserAgentAnalyzer Analyzer
        {
            get
            {
                if (analyzer == null)
                {
                    analyzer = Builder.Build();
                }
                return analyzer;
            }
        }

        static YauaaSingleton()
        {
            Builder = UserAgentAnalyzer.NewBuilder();
            Builder.DropTests();
            Builder.DelayInitialization();
            Builder.WithCache(100);
            Builder.HideMatcherLoadStats();
            Builder.WithAllFields();
        }


    }
```

in your controller you can read the user agent from http headers:

```
string userAgent = Request.Headers?.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key.ToLower() == "user-agent").Value;
```

Then you can parse the user agent:

```
 var ua = YauaaSingleton.Analyzer.Parse(userAgent );

 var browserName = ua.Get(UserAgent.AGENT_NAME).GetValue();
```

you can also get the confidence level (higher is better):

```
 var confidence = ua.Get(UserAgent.AGENT_NAME).GetConfidence();
```

Comment: do you test in **NET 6**?

Comment: Sorry I didn't worked on that project by a while, I hope to resume it soon. If you found issues report them to github.

Answer (score 0):

In production application it is important to check first if user agent exists.

```
public static string GetUserAgent(this HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(HeaderNames.UserAgent, out var userAgent))
    {
        return userAgent.ToString();
    }
    return "Not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var userAgent = $"{this.Request?.HttpContext?.Request?.Headers["user-agent"]}";
```