# How to get Requested browser name and version in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to get Requested browser name and version in asp.net core 2.0

[How to get user Browser name ( user-agent ) in Asp.net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664770/how-to-get-user-browser-name-user-agent-in-asp-net-core) returns all the browser installed on client PC. 
But I need the browser name currently requesting.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get user Browser name ( user-agent ) in Asp.net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664770/how-to-get-user-browser-name-user-agent-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: No, the header *doesn't* return all browsers. It can't - the header is sent by the browser itself. *That's* the name by which every browser in every OS identifies itself to sites. That string identifies compatibility with existing browsers, the version of the browser's rendering engine and the OS.

Comment: BTW why are you asking? Browser detection is *not* a good idea if you want to control how a page is rendered. Browsers can lie. All major browsers are evergreen which means they update themselves every month. You can't map browser versions to features or capabilities. That's why all sites use feature detection for the last 5+ years

Comment: Headers["User-Agent"] returns
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36."

Then which one is currently requesting?

Answer (score 3):

Use `install-package Wangkanai.Detection -pre` and `install-package Wangkanai.Detection.Browser -pre`   in **PM** to install package.
Then... Write  the following code in *Startup.cs*:

```
services.AddDetection();
services.AddDetectionCore().AddBrowser();
```

In your *Controller*:

```
private readonly IDetection _detection;
        public HomeController(IDetection detection)
        {
            _detection = detection;
        }
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            string browser_info = _detection.Browser.Type.ToString() + _detection.Browser.Version;
            ViewData["a"] = browser_info;
            return View(_detection);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this `Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString()`

Comment: It returns  all the browser installed.
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36".

But I need the client browser name currently using