# Get information from a load function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, controller

I'm creating a .Net Core application.

I wanted to know if there is a solution for my issue.

At the moment, I'm created a function which is load like that :

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', browser);
} else {
    window.attachEvent('onload', browser);
}

function browser() {

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") !== -1) {
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") !== -1)
            console.log("Microsoft Edge");
        else
            console.log("Chrome");
    }
    else if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1 ) {
        console.log("Opera")
    }
    else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) {
        console.log('Safari');
    }
    else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
        console.log('Firefox');
    }
    else if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true)) //IF IE > 10
    {
        console.log('IE');
    }
    else {
        console.log('unknown');
    }

}
```

And I wanted to know if I change the console.log by return, if it will be possible to get the different return value in a controller ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The ASP.NET Core on server side has no way to know a returned value executed in a browser .  To do that , you have no choice but to make a request to send the information to the server .

Comment: Even if I use AJAX ?

Comment: it's certain that it will work if you use Ajax , as in that case you will make a request .

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you could determine the browser on the server side, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664770/how-to-get-user-browser-name-user-agent-in-asp-net-core