# the type or namespace name 'HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase' does not exist in the namespace 'System.web' in .net core 2.2

Tags: c#, browser, asp.net-core-2.2, system.web, httpbrowsercapabilities

I am getting the title error when I do the code in **.netcore2.2**.

Following is my code,

```
var browser = Request.Browser;
System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase myBrowserCaps = browser;
```

**HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase** in this keyword it showing me the title error.

While this code is working perfectly **below** the .netcore2.2. 
**HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase** is the interface of **System.web** DLL below the .netcore2.2.

It means the updated .net framework this namespace is not exist now which namespace is work, that I am not getting.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which information you need, you could look that up in the headers (e.g. `Request.Headers["User-Agent"]` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664770/how-to-get-user-browser-name-user-agent-in-asp-net-core)) instead, or get it using a library like [Device Detection](https://github.com/51Degrees/dotNET-Device-Detection/issues/10).

Edit: Here is a tutorial for getting the device type information using the `ASP.NET Core Detection` library:

- Install the `Wangkanai.Detection` NuGet package.
- Add to the `ConfigureServices` method in your `Startup.cs`:

  ```
  services.AddDetection();
  ```
- In the controller inject: `IDeviceResolver deviceResolver`
- ... and get the device information via: `deviceResolver.Device.Type`, e.g.:

  ```
  var isMobile = deviceResolver.Device.Type == DeviceType.Mobile;
  var isDesktop = deviceResolver.Device.Type == DeviceType.Desktop;
  ...
  ```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/wangkanai/Detection) for further information.

Comment: I dont want the browser name, I want the condition that my webapplication is working in computer browser or in mobile browser?

Comment: I added an example using the `ASP.NET Core Detection` library for getting the device type.