# How to get user device type in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Can you please let me know how to get the device type in .net core 3.1? I have tried the below sample but it gives me all available options.

```
this.Request.HttpContext.GetServerVariable("HTTP_USER_AGENT");
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "device type"? Smartphone/tablet/laptop/desktop?

Comment: User Agent is a HTTP header in the message not a type.  Some headers you get by name and other the Net Library has predefined type like User Agent .See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664770/how-to-get-user-browser-name-user-agent-in-asp-net-core/50435244?force_isolation=true

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem. Why do you believe you need to know the type of device? What actual problem are you trying to solve with that information? Testing the user agent string is generally a bad idea https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent.

Comment: I will have a social campaign link. Clicking on the link, I should know the device type from which you has clicked the link and accessed the application @JeremyLakeman

Comment: @BalanjaneyuluK Why do you need to know the device type? How is that information used?

Comment: These helpful links could give you some ideas for device detection. (1) [Device Type Detection info](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/792dc880-8d12-426b-98ca-61e34dcab2e0/device-type-detection-info?forum=aspmvc) (2) [How to Track Browsing Device and Orientation in ASP.Net](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/how-to-track-browsing-device-and-orientation-in-Asp-Net/) You could use the logic in your app to find the device type.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to know the user's browser and some information about their device then you could make a test with the [UAParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UAParser/)

It could return browser names and OS-related information that could help you predict the device type.

I tried to make a test using .Net Core 6 project and it works. So it should not have any issue with the .Net Core 3.1 project.

You could refer to the example below.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
     <p>You are using @Model.Message</p>
</div>
```

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
   public string Message { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        var userAgent = HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
        var uaParser = Parser.GetDefault();
        ClientInfo c = uaParser.Parse(userAgent);
        this.Message = c.ToString();
    }
```

Output in different browsers:

[image]

Further, you could make a tests with different devices to check for the results.

Reference is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52609204/10309381).