# How Do I Use 51 Degrees Mobile Device Detection with a Razor Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, 51degrees

I have an ASP.Net Core 5.0 web application that I need to detect mobile devices for. I downloaded the 51 Degrees NuGet Package using the Visual Studio Nuget Package Manager, but I cannot figure out how to use it from a Razor Page and cannot find any examples of it being used with Razor Pages anywhere.

So far it looks like the best example I can find is at https://51degrees.com/developers/documentation/apis/netv32/tutorials/getting-started but it says "This tutorial assumes you are building this from within the 51Degrees Visual Studio solution." Like most people I already have a solution for my app which I need to use 51 Degrees with and cannot create a new 51Degrees Visual Studio solution. Plus, the example has way more code than I want to use. I want something that works like Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice without requiring more work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086856/mobile-device-detection-in-asp-net/13086894 detecting mobile device resolves mainly around parsing the "HTTP_USER_AGENT"

Comment: I know and I've ghetto rigged my own in the past, but I want something more reliable which is why I am trying to use 51

Comment: You want more dependencies in your projects?

Comment: Well, so far I've got it working somewhat but sometimes I get an error saying: InvalidOperationException: This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request.
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.CheckDisposedOrStarted()

Answer (score 0):

Hi @WannabePuppetMaster,

51Degrees Device Detection solution can be used in similar manner as with AspNet MVC as described in this [example](http://51degrees.com/documentation/4.3/_examples__device_detection__web_integration__examples.html).

The main difference is where the `Device Data` is obtained and made available to a `Page`. In MVC, the data is obtained in the `Controller` before passing to the `View`, while in Razor Page it will need to be obtained in the `Page Model` so that the `Page` can access it via the `Model` object.

You can find more details in this [comment](https://github.com/51Degrees/device-detection-dotnet/issues/19#issuecomment-1005724261) with examples.

You can find more examples (in various languages) and information from the [documentation](http://51degrees.com/documentation/4.3/_examples__device_detection__web_integration__examples.html). For .NET specific details, please see `Language Specific` section.